# Are there Olympiad problems that can be solved using split-complex numbers?

Tags: contest-math, extension-field, split-complex-numbers

There are various uses for [complex numbers in Math Olympiads](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-8176-4449-0_5). In addition, quadratic number fields are sometimes useful, for instance for [Pell equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation).

**Are there any Olympiad/contest problems that can be solved using [split-complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_numbers) ($a+jb$, $j^2=1$)?**

Comment: While I'm not aware of such problems, you might be able to construct ones of your own, e.g. by changing circle problems into hyperbola problems.

Comment: But more generally, the split-complex equivalents of your link's Euclidean geometry problems will typically be in hyperbolic geometry instead, which may be why they're not used in Olympiads.

Comment: The split-complex numbers are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ so in some sense you can't really compute anything with them you couldn't just compute with ordinary real numbers. They're nice for making the analogies between ordinary and hyperbolic trigonometry more precise but they're not actually super useful.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan True, but the complex numbers are isomorphic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ in some sense, too, aren't they? If I understand correctly the norm is different though, and the one for the split-complex numbers is "more interesting" since it does not coincide with the Euclidean norm but with a hyperbolic one.

Comment: @Federico: not as a ring!

Answer (score 2):

Just made this up.

> Show that the product of 2 integers, each of which can be written as the difference of 2 squares, can again be written as the difference of 2 squares.

The algebraic approach would involve showing

$$ ( a + bj) ( c + dj) = (ac+ bd) + (ad + bc) j. $$

Of course, the number theoretic approach is slightly more direct. We use the classification that a number $n$ can be written as the difference of 2 squares iff it is either 1) odd, or 2) a multiple of 4.

Comment: Hardly an Olympiad-level problem.

Comment: @J.G. I disagree; I can easily imagine seeing something of this difficulty level at the regional stage of the Italian Olympiad. This seems a nice reasonable answer.

Comment: @J.G. I do not disagree with you, as it depends on which olympiad you're referring to. My intention was to draw the parallel with Fermat's 2 square identity (which is for addition of 2 squares), in which case one sees the analogous approach of Split-Complex numbers. Given that Fermat's 2 square identify is a well-known and sometimes used fact, we can look at similar olympiad problems and see if we can tweak them slightly.